# I generated the model.tflite in conda, but no metadata while i try to run in android studio. How to generate multi-class label.txt to attach to it?

Tags: android

I tried to generate multi-class label.txt which means the name of subfolder for each class... not multi-label for those images...
I created the tflite.model in Conda environment using KERAS library....
But no metadata in it... so i wondering how to create multi-class label.txt before i could implement the tflite.model with metadata in a smartphone through android studio?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add metadata to the TfLite Model to make it compatible with the current version of the tflite dependencies . If you do not want to add metadata to your model and still want to make it run , then you need to degrade your dependency version and remove the code which asks for metadata from the Interpreter .

If you want to add metadata then you need to supply your model and the basics of your model , to a script which will provide you with the required tflite + metadata as an output . More of the same can be found at :

> https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata

There are already scripts available which will help to convert your model to another model which has metadata in it . The scripts can be found at :

> https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata_writer_tutorial

Follow the above given links to achieve your goals

Comment: Ask here , if you have more questions